# jQuery - removeClass after all inputs have received focus?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form with the three sub-groups of inputs (of various kinds). The sub-groups are denoted by class names (.group_1, .group_2, .group_3).

What I would like to do is this:

Once all inputs of a specific class (e.g. .group_1), have received focus (or been changed, either would work), the class of a separate span is removed (using removeClass, assumedly). If only 4 of 5 inputs within a specific class have received focus (or been changed), the class would remain on the span until the 5th is focused or changed.

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something straightforward like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/7EUas/

```
var selectedMarkerClass = 'was-selected';

$('.group_1').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).addClass(selectedMarkerClass);

    if ($('.' + selectedMarkerClass).length == $('.group_1').length) {
        $('div').text('each input was selected at least once');
    }
});​
```

?

Comment: Ah! Beat me to it. I was jsfiddling and came up with essentially the same type of solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tomtheman5/dB2Gs/

Comment: This solution actually looks like it might work really well, and I appreciate your response.  I changed `.on('focus')` to `.change()` so that I could force a change to the input.  As a follow up, how can I manipulate it so that any radio button within a group will be seen as a change? In other words, if radio button "Yes" is changed to radio button "No" (same name attribute), is there a way to have that change add to the `selectedMarkerClass` (as per your example)? Thanks!

Comment: I might add, I'd like to do this without creating individual selectors for every input. The form I'm working with has hundreds of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some pseudo classes to mark inputs as focused on `focus` event and check has they all been focused. If yes, then remove class from your span.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="group1 red">Test span</span>

<div id="group1-container">
    <input class="group1" type="text" />
    <input class="group1" type="text" />
    <input class="group1" type="text" />
    <input class="group1" type="text" />
    <input class="group1" type="text" />
</div>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
group1Container$ = $('#group1-container');
group1$ = $('input.group1', group1Container$);
group1$.on('focus', function() {
    var input$ = $(this);
    input$.addClass('focused');
    if(!$('input.group1:not(.focused)', group1Container$).length) {
        $('span.group1').removeClass('red');
        group1$.off('focus');
    }
});
```

**[​DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/GFwvX/)**